# How to add comparing to ON CONFLICT () DO UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I need to check, if in table there are any operations with current user for today.
Usually I compare time in this way: `timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date`

Could you please help, how to do it in INSERT in ON CONFLICT () DO UDPATE?

```
        INSERT INTO table (login, smth, timestamp)
          VALUES ('username', 'smth', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        ON CONFLICT (login, timestamp) DO UPDATE
          SET smth = 'smth'
              timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Here will be exactly comparing of timestamp, but I need to check, if it's for today, like above: `timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date`

Thanks!

Comment: Is that `=` an assignment or a comparison?

Comment: in last and previous lines? That's assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the timestamp but have a unique constraint on the date, then you can do that easily in the most recent versions of Postgres using a computed column.  This requires adding a new column which is the date into the table:

```
create table t (
     login text,
     smth text,
     ts timestamp,
     ts_date date generated always as (ts::date) stored
);
```

And then creating a unique constraint:

```
create unique index unq_t_login_timestamp on t(login, ts_date);
```

Now you can use `on conflict`:

```
INSERT INTO t (login, smth, ts)
    VALUES ('username', 'smth', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ON CONFLICT (login, ts_date) DO UPDATE
          SET smth = 'smth',
              ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6d37203093ac37fad7f10707b7260ffc) is the code in a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

It is better to eschew the computed column and just use:

```
create unique index unq_t_login_timestamp on t(login, (timestamp::date));
```

Comment: Thanks you! But I guess, that's not what I'm looking exactly. I need to compare time nor in ms and not even in seconds, but in days. But I have to save in DB timestamp in ms (not data-format). I hope, I could now explain, what I wanted

Comment: @SardorkhujaTukhtakhodjayev . . . This does do the comparison in days and stores the value as a complete timestamp.  Did you try running the code?  The SQL Fiddle shows that the value changes.

Comment: You can don't really need the computed column, so this would also be possible with older Postgres versions: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e027d16a060a1a93099849e5209cedd3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I thought that was possible, but when I tried, I got a syntax error.  I must've had some other typo.  One of the hazards of actually testing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CTE, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql).

In case of your question, the query is like below:
(However, I'm not clear what "timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date" means.)

```
with
"data"("w_login","w_smth","w_timestamp") as (
  select 'username2'::text, 'smth'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
),
"update" as (
  update "table" set ("smth","timestamp")=("w_smth","w_timestamp") from "data"
  where "login"="w_login" and "w_timestamp">CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date
  returning *
)
insert into "table"
select * from "data"
where not exists (select * from "update");
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUcN2YW5qb4tWcRnRhXVXa/1)